# How can i make my app appear on tablets

Tags: android, google-play, manifest

I've made an app that can be shown on tablets but it only appeared in the market when opening the play store from a phone and that was because I've added a uses-permission that is not compatible with tablets but then I added that required is false:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission 
     android:required="false"        
     android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission
     android:required="false"
     android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Should I add the screen sizes that are compatible in the manifest or is it ok not to? I mean if I didn't add which screens are compatible will all the screen be compatible?

plus I want to know please how can I upload a new apk with the changes without notifying the user that updates were made because I haven't added anything just changed the manifest a little bit...

tried to upload my app with same version code but failed they asked me to change the version code so what should I do and how can I upload same apk without notying the user of an update...
plz I need to know this too!! how can I upload it without showing the user an update notification?

thank u very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so based on my researches we can't add the same apk unless we increased the version code number and by that the users get an update notification...
Secondly I don't think that it's really important to add which screens are compatible with this app because by default all the screens are, because even though I didn't add anything about the screens they wrote in my app that all the screen sizes are compatible..

another thing is because I wanna do a small change and wanna upload a new apk and users will get an update notification I won't do this update unless when I do some other changes in the app that way the user will see that some new features were added that's why he needs to update the app and that we're not just bothering him...

that's based on my own searches...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenSize=“large” android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize=“large android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize=“xlarge” android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize=“xlarge android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

[refer this android doc for more detail](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for Nexus7 availability:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!--no small size screens -->


    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>
```

For xxhdpi devices you can use 480 as an int value:

```
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
```